# One device doesn't receive push notifications (GCM)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have old Motorolla Droid Razor (Android 4.0.4) which doesn't receive push notifications.

I had a problem receive push notifications on it from my app. Initially I thought that I am doing something wrong (there are a lot of small things which break it).

I got GcmClient (Google's sample app - https://code.google.com/p/gcm/) built it and tried it. It works fine on other phones, but doesn't work on this one.

On this phone tt can:
a) Find Google Play Services
b) It can register and get regid.
c) It can send an echo message and it comes back

However, it never receives messages from the server.

I use the same WiFi for several phones. This rules out issues with firewall.

I tried to hard reset the phone (to make sure that I am getting the latest Google Play Services).

Any ideas? Has anybody seen issue like that?

Comment: did you try getting a [`return receipt`](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#receipts) ack from gcm ? Just have this client id, and see what return receipt says.